# How to remove space between flexes in react native?(flexWrap)

Tags: react-native

How to remove space between flex. (***spaces is marked in green***)
I am currently using flex-wrap: 'wrap', and flat list with 2 columns. I am trying to archive something like google keep

My code:-

```js
<FlatList
  data={[
    { storeName: 'The Look' },
    { storeName: 'STYLO' },
    { storeName: 'Bombshell studio' },
    { storeName: 'STYLO1' },
    { storeName: 'The Look2' },
    { storeName: 'STYLOe' },
    { storeName: 'STYdLO1' },
    { storeName: 'Thed Look2' },
    { storeName: 'STdYLOe' },
  ]}
  numColumns={2}
  columnWrapperStyle={{
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingLeft: 15,
  }}
  containerStyle={{
    width: '100%',
  }}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ARecentBooking key={item.storeName} storeName={item.storeName} />
  )}>
</FlatList>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also add `ARecentBooking`? How does it look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method 1:- I manage to get the result with some workaround:-

```
    <ScrollView style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
       //put two faltlist
       <Flatlist scrollEnabled={false}/>
       <Flatlist scrollEnabled={false}/>
    <ScrollView/>
```

put items of the odd index in the first flatlist
and even items in the second flatList

```
function separateArrays(array) {
    let arr1=[]
    let arr2=[]
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(i%2 === 0) {
            arr1.push(array[i])
        }
        else{
            arr2.push(array[i])
        }
    }
    return [arr1, arr2]
}
```

method 2:-It also can be done using .map function

```
       <ScrollView>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 15 }}>
                <View>
                    {arr1.map((item, index) => {
                        return <ARecentBooking key={item.storeName} item={item} />
                    })}
                </View>
                <View>
                    {arr2.map((item, index) => {
                        return <ARecentBooking key={item.storeName} item={item} />
                    })}
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the UI as shown below

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DeviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default function App() {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.Card}>
      {/* ALl Other COde here...Like the 15 AUG and everything */}
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={[
          { storeName: 'The Look' },
          { storeName: 'STYLO' },
          { storeName: 'Bombshell studio' },
          { storeName: 'STYLO1' },
          { storeName: 'The Look2' },
          { storeName: 'STYLOe' },
          { storeName: 'STYdLO1' },
          { storeName: 'Thed Look2' },
          { storeName: 'STdYLOe' },
        ]}
        numColumns={2}
        columnWrapperStyle={{
          flex: 1,
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          width: '100%',
        }}
        renderItem={renderItem}></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  Card: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFEAEC',
    minHeight: 150,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 12,
    maxWidth: DeviceWidth / 2 - 20,
  },
});
```

Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/flatlist-row-card) for the same.

Here's a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjZU.jpg) of the result.

Comment: this does not work. Check this out:-https://snack.expo.dev/fGaMcjg96

Comment: I do not want to fill the space with the item.. I want to achieve a layout the same as google keep..

Comment: okay.. check this out:- https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsrHS57YPlM34WnS4yy9LentfXLw